# Create DDS Texture From Memory

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx-11

Okay so I know how to use CreateDDSTextureFromFile() function, but let's say that I have DDS file in memory via void *Buffer, UINT Len... How can I create Texture from this variables?

I know that there is a CreateDDSTextureFromMemory() function but I really don't know how to use this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can already do this:

```
hr = CreateDDSTextureFromFile(pDevice, L"texture.dds", nullptr, &pSRV);
```

The following should work:

```
hr = CreateDDSTextureFromMemory(pDevice, Buffer, Len, nullptr, &pSRV);
```